# MongoDB findAndModify element in array

Tags: mongodb

I have the data like below:

```
{
info:{
    id:0000,
    name:"Iot name",
    vendor:"some vendor",
},
location:[
    {
        lat:0,
        lng:0,
        status:3,
        locID:"uniqueID0"
    },{
        lat:1,
        lng:1,
        status:0,
        locID:"uniqueID1"
    },{
        lat:2,
        lng:2,
        status:1,
        locID:"uniqueID2"
    }
]}
```

Need example like **findAndModify** or something else similar, to find
in the iots collection, location with a unique ID and change his status.

e.g Find in collection **iot**, element with **id**=**0000** and location with **locID**="**uniqueID1**" and set status for that location into 2

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the [**`$set`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operator together with the **[`$` positional operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)** in your update to change set the `status` field for that location to 2. The **[`$` positional operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)** will identify the correct element in the array to update without explicitly specifying the position of the element in the array, thus your final update statement should look like:

```
db.iost.update(
    { 
        "info.id": 0000,
        "location.locID": "uniqueID1"   
    }, 
    {
        "$set": {
            "location.$.status": 2
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: Yes! This is it what I was looking for. Thanks alot